# ajax loop and append dynamic data parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, dynamic

This works…

```
$.ajax({url: '../cfc/saveData.cfc', data: {method: 'addAccountInfo', acctID: aID, firstName: firstName, lastName: astName, address1: address1, address2: address2, phone1: phone1, phone2: phone2, rowID:i, modId: modId}, success: function(data){return true;}});
```

But I want to do this dynamically in a loop
This is in the loop …

```
fld += jsArray[c] + ": '" + col + "', ";
```

**jsArray[c]** is the field names (firstName, lastName, address1, address2, phone1, phone2)

**col** are the values (Monica, Jones, 626 Hollow Bridge Lane, (555) 555-5555)
I remove the last comma

```
fld = fld.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
```

**fld** looks like this

firstName: 'Monica', lastName: 'Jones', address1: '626 Hollow Bridge Lane', Phone1: '(555) 555-5555'

if address2 and phone2 aren’t filled out, it doesn’t get included.
I want to use ajax …

```
$.ajax({url: '../cfc/saveData.cfc', data: {method: 'addAccountInfo', acctID: aID, fld, rowID:i, modId: modId}, success: function(data){return true;}});
```

It’s not saving but if I write each field in like the first one above, then it works.  Is there a way to get something like this to work.
Can this be done and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then instead of appending your key value pairs to a string you can simply create the object directly like this:

```
var data = {};

// Assuming a loop would be around this part
var key = jsArray[c];
var value = col;
data[key] = value;
```

And then you can pass it to your ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({url: '../cfc/saveData.cfc', data: data, success: function(data){return true;}});
```